# Disk Cleanup wants to clean a lot of temporary files

Tags: disk-cleanup

Windows 7 Disk Cleanup thinks I have 72 GB of temporary files that it's offering to delete. From what I saw in other questions, it tries to delete from the Users directory; according to WinDirStat, my Users directory is only 77 GB total. Is there a way to see what, specifically, Disk Cleanup is counting? There's no "view files" button for temporary files.

Answer (score 2):

Run Disk Cleanup, select the category and press "View Files"

To view the **TEMP** folder contents when the "View Files" button is unavailable. you can open an explorer window and type **%temp%**. This will open the TEMP folder ("%Temp%" is global ENV:VAR).

> Everything in that **TEMP** folder is and should be temporary and can
>   be deleted. Unless an app that you used was programmed wrong or a
>   malicious app downloaded some large files into that folder. If you 
>   see an app running from the **TEMP** folder it is more than likely malicious.
>
> **ADDITION** (by Pyscogeek)**:** Or you have just installed something or done
>   updates and have not yet re-booted the system. You should reboot before delete.

Disk Cleanup does not delete user files.
It does delete the following:

- Compression of old files
- Temporary Internet files
- Temporary Windows files
- Downloaded program files
- Recycle Bin
- Removal of unused applications or optional Windows components
- Setup log files
- Off-line files

System Files

- Previous Windows installations
- Windows Defender files
- Windows Update files
- Windows upgrade

This is not a complete list.

Comment: The Windows 7 Disk Cleanup tool states, "You can safely delete temporary files that have **not been modified in over a week**" - so I would assume this rule is followed when allowing the Disk Cleanup tool to perform the task.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to see what those "Temporary Files" are then use Piriform's Ccleaner. The program also can delete LOTS of other files.